# Why is my div too wide?

Tags: css, layout

In the screen capture below, you can see from the horizontal scroll bar that there's hidden horizontal space in the viewport. The grey div at the bottom is what scrolls. The image doesn't. Why is this?

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
table, tr {
  margin: 0px;
}

table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e0e0f0;
}

body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

button {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.theheader {
  background-image: url("images/qr1920x960x4.png");

  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vw;

  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

  overflow-x: hidden;

  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #202020;
}

.therest {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(32, 32, 32, 1.0);
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Quotient Ring</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="procedural, planet, generation">
<script type="text/javascript" src="chooseMass.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="globalConstants.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="brentsRand.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="starsystem.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="star.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="planet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="theMainFunction()">
<!-- <body> -->
  <!-- <div class="theheader"><img src="images/qr960x480x8.png"></img></div>  -->
  <div class="theheader"></div>
  <div class="therest">
    <p id="makeNewSystemButton"></p>
    <p id="planetsTable"></p>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

Here is the relevent js code that builds the table:

```
var htmlString = "";
htmlString += "<p style=\"font-size:small;font-family:Consolas\">";
htmlString += "Star:</br>";
htmlString += "Type " + starSystem.star.spectralClass + starSystem.star.luminosityClass + "</br>";
htmlString += "Luminosity " + starSystem.star.luminosity.toPrecision(3);
htmlString += "</p>";

// semimajorAxis, mass, radius, temperature, pressure, atm, clouds, hyd, frosts
htmlString += "<table style=\"font-size:small;font-family:Consolas;border:1px solid black\">";

// A lot of code that probably doesn't matter. Just ask if you need to see it.

htmlString += "</table>";
document.getElementById("planetsTable").innerHTML += htmlString;
```

Hope this isn't too much to wade through.

By the way, how quickly does hair grow back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because of the `width:100vw` in `.theader` css rule. This can be solved if you use `width:100%` instead.

Explanation here: https://bitsofco.de/viewport-vs-percentage-units/

> The vw unit determines its size based on the width of the viewport. However, browsers calculate the viewport size as the browser window, which includes the space for the scrollbar.
>   [image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/wek2z339/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your `<td>`'s padding. You use `width: 100vw;` on their container, but their padding adds width.

Change your `td` style to this:

```
td {
  padding: 0px;
}
```